# Entity Framework group by and get max

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Lets say I've table with the structure as below:

`MyRow:`

```
Id Name Date
1  A    2015/01/01
2  B    2015/01/01
3  C    2015/01/02
4  A    2015/01/03
5  B    2015/01/03
6  A    2015/01/02
7  C    2015/01/01
```

Using EF I would like to get list of MyRow which would contain elements with distinct names and newest date so in this case it would be:

```
4 A 2015/01/03
5 B 2015/01/03
3 C 2015/01/02
```

I started with something like this:

```
var myRows = context.MyRows.GroupBy(mr => mr.Name).Select(..now wth with max..)
```

Answer (score 6):

Order each group and take the last of each.

Or since EF doesn't (last time I checked) support `Last()`, order each group in reverse and take the first:

```
var myRows = context.MyRows
  .GroupBy(mr => mr.Name)
  .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(mr => mr.Date).First());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = context.MyRows.Group(p => p.Name)
                    .Select(g => new { 
                                      Type = g.Key, 
                                      Date = g.OrderByDescending(p => p.Date)
                                              .FirstOrDefault()
                                     }
```

Comment: Then you need to do `var myRows = data.Select(x => x.Date)` to get the `MyRow` you've put in the field called `Date` and then if you take that and simplify out things you aren't using (`Type = g.Key`) or that can't be hit (replace `FirstOrDefault` with `First`) you end up with my answer.